# SSIS Attunity Teradata connector doesn't connect

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata, attunity

An Attunity connector for Teradata stopped working on a server that I use. I am just doing a simple Teradata Source. The connection manager connects because I can successfully test the connection with the "test connection" button in the manager.

At first the error was about a missing driver, so I installed driver version 15.00.04 from this [link](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/windows)

Now the new error that I get is:
[Teradata Source [2](http://forums.attunity.com/forums/microsoft-ssis-teradata-connector/error-teradata-tpt-registry-key-cannot-1434.html)] Error: The Teradata TPT registry key cannot be opened. Verify that the TPT API 12.0 or 13.0 Edition 2 (13.0.0.2) for Windows x64 is installed properly.

A possible [solution](http://forums.attunity.com/forums/microsoft-ssis-teradata-connector/error-teradata-tpt-registry-key-cannot-1434.html) was to duplicate and rename the TPT key, however, I don't think I have a TPT key or I can't find it. Any advice, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are load/unload utilities that come with the Teradata installers. There is a TPT utility which you would need to install. I would recommend installing all the utilities not just TPT. Below is a link to the TPT utility:

http://www.teradata.com/tools-and-utilities/load-and-unload/?LangType=1033&LangSelect=true

This provides a TPT key and SSIS then runs with the Teradata source.